# Using $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ to find an inequality of $P(A\cup B)$.

Tags: probability-theory

I've been struggling with the following question for a few days now, where $P(A) = \frac{3}{4}$ and $P(B) = \frac{1}{3}$, and i need to show that $\frac{3}{4} \leq P(A\cup B) \leq 1$ . While also finding the lower and upperbounds for $P(A \cap B)$ as well.

Comment: We have the following relation for any events $A$ and $B$  $\rightarrow P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$. For any event $S$, what is the range of $P(S)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visualizing this scenario as a Venn diagram, $P(A\cup B)$ would be the smallest if $A$ and $B$ entirely overlap, in which case $P(A\cup B)=P(A)=3/4$.

On the other hand, $P(A\cup B)$ would be the largest if $A$ and $B$ are as disjoint as possible, in which case $A$ and $B$ would take up the entire sample space since $P(A)+P(B)>1$. Thus the maximum possible value of $P(A\cup B)$ is $1$.

---

In general, $$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$

So for this situation, 
$$\begin{align}
P(A\cup B) &= \frac34+\frac13-P(A\cap B) \\
P(A\cup B) &= \frac{13}{12}-P(A\cap B)\\
\end{align}$$

Substituting the maximum and minimum possible values of $P(A\cup B)$ will give you the bounds of $P(A\cap B)$.

Can you take it from here?